# Is it possible for a model ID to contain date when its made?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a model, that needs an ID that contains the date that its made, and if there are more than one made that day, they need to have a number attached to it like so:

> 15122019
>
> 16122019-1
>
> 16122019-2
>
> 17122019

something like this, and it would need to be made automatically, no input from the user..
is this possible?
this is how my model looks right now:

```
public class RaidRequest
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Permissions Access { get; set; }
    [Required]        
    public Group UserOrAdmin { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UNCPath { get; set; }
   
}
```

How would this be possible?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, are you expecting to store `string` type data in an `int` type variable?

Comment: the `int` is just temporary for checking if the system works.

Comment: whats is the ID in the database ? 
is it varchar ? or int or date ???

Comment: for now its `int` but it probably needs to be `string`

Comment: @RenārsTreimanis it needs to *remain* an int, be autogenerated by the database (using IDENTITY or SEQUENCE) and contain *no* business information. "Smart" keys are not a smart idea at all

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos so its not possible to make it contain the date ?

Comment: Are you using entity framework or sql (stored procs) to save your data? Based on your response, the solution to your problem will differ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. However to have such formatting `16122019-1` you need string column. Such logic should be implemented on the Bussiness layer

Also, you have to take into account concurrent inserts, if the system is highly loaded, to have correct increment value

---

Code improvements: 
Your request model should not have fields which are not used (like `Id`). It's better to have several DTO for each level: API, Business Logic, Database.

Comment: how would I do this? where to create this string column?

Comment: what exactly would i write there?

Comment: @RenārsTreimanis In your business logic or wherever you will insert your entry into your table: `Id= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"1"`, where 1 would be the number that you will place. You will need some logic to persist this value.

Comment: But do you want to make those ```date + number (1, 2,3)```  number fields to auto incremented?

Comment: Yes that would be the preferred result